# Subequation numbering in iopart

Tags: cross-referencing, eqnarray

Given a system of equations (1a), (1b), etc. I want to be able to reference both (1a) and the entire system (1). This is trivial with `subequations`, but in an `iopart` document this environment does not seem to be supported (no `amsmath`, I guess) and the recommendation is to use `\numparts ... \endnumparts`. However, with `\numparts`, I cannot manage to reference properly. First, `eqnarray`s do not seem to be referenceable (not an issue with `numparts`, but still), and second, even if I put everything into `equation` environments which are referenceable, I still cannot refer to the entire system.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\begin{document}
    
    \section{Example}
    
    \numparts\begin{eqnarray} \label{system1}
    a=1, \\
    b=2
    \end{eqnarray}\endnumparts
    
    \numparts\begin{equation} \label{system2a}
    a=1
    \end{equation}\begin{equation} \label{system2b}
    b=2
    \end{equation}\endnumparts
    
    \cref{system1} should read (1) but instead labels the section\\
    \cref{system2a,system2b} should read (2) but instead reads (2a) and (2b)\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iopart` class makes several fundamental errors, the main one doing a silly thing that makes it incompatible with `amsmath`.

I tried to contact the support team, but got no answer at all.

Another error is in the definition of `\numparts` where the `equation` counter is stepped with `\addtocounter` instead of `\refstepcounter`.

However, `eqnarray` doesn't behave well with `cleveref`, so in order to refer to the single equations you need to use the plain `\ref`.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\crefname{equation}{}{}

\patchcmd{\numparts}{\addtocounter{equation}{1}}{\refstepcounter{equation}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{8} % just to test
    
\section{Example}
    
\begin{numparts}\label{system1}
\begin{eqnarray}
  a&=&1,\label{system1a}\\
  b&=&2\label{system1b}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{numparts}
\begin{numparts}\label{system2}
\begin{equation} \label{system2a}
  a=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{system2b}
  b=2
\end{equation}
\end{numparts}

\cref{system1} refers to the first system; separately \ref{system1a} and \ref{system1b}

\cref{system2} refers to the second system; separately \cref{system2a,system2b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I'd simply ignore what the people at IOP think and use `amsmath`.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}

% for using amsmath
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{\textit{\alph{equation}}}{}{}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{equation}{}{}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{8} % just to test
    
\section{Example}
    
\begin{subequations}\label{system1}
\begin{align}
  a&=1,\label{system1a}\\
  b&=2\label{system1b}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}\label{system2}
\begin{equation} \label{system2a}
  a=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{system2b}
  b=2
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\cref{system1} refers to the first system; separately \cref{system1a,system1b}

\cref{system2} refers to the second system; separately \cref{system2a,system2b}

\end{document}
```

I bet they wouldn't discover it. The patch to emulate the output of `iopart` with the subequation letter in italics has to be made before loading `cleveref`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!