# Center an equation without using amsmath?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I'm writing in a document class (iopart) that is not compatible with amsmath (!!). My equations are fine but not centered, how can I center them without using amsmath?

Comment: Short answer: without heavily hacking into the code of `iopart` you can't. If you are publishing with them you should keep their style; if you are not publishing with them you should consider using another class.

Comment: See my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560844/4427 However, consider that using the code that makes `iopart.cls` compatible with `amsmath` may cause rejection of your submission.

Comment: Thank you both! I will go with the Journal's style I'm afraid...