# Small fractions in the iopart document class

Tags: amsmath

I used to type many documents with `amsmath` package. Now I need to prepare a document with the `iopart` class. This class is incompatible with `amsmath`. How should I type then the `\tfrac` command? Somehow I could not find an answer here or on the Internet.

Comment: `{\textstyle\frac{a}{b}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much, don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: See my code (the second block) in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560844/4427 that shows how to use `amsmath` with `iopart`. I believe they won't notice.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I am surprised by no reaction response of the `iopart` support following your email.

Comment: @yarchik Well, I just tried downloading `iopart.cls` from the IOP site and it's still at version 0.0 1996/06/10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `\tfrac` as `{\textstyle\frac{a}{b}}` if `amsmath` is not usable.